# How can I merge two rows into one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query output is like this, I need to be this in one row.

```
 iProductM  iProductO   UnitCostM   UnitCostO
    7065    NULL         30.67      NULL
    NULL    7065         NULL       29.78
```

Required output:

```
iProductM   iProductO   UnitCostM   UnitCostO
        7065     7065        30.67      29.78
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(iProductM, iProductO) as P,
    coalesce(UnitCostM, UnitCostO) as U  
FROM 
    ViewForCostAll 
WHERE
    iProductO = 7065 OR iProductM = 7065
```

But my output is still in two rows:

```
P       U
7065    30.67
7065    29.78
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why dont you just  find [min/max](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5386) of all columns ?

Comment: its a cost,i cant take min or max

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(iProductM, iProductO) as iProductM,
    coalesce(iProductO, iProductM) as iProductM,
    coalesce(UnitCostM, UnitCostO) as UnitCostM,  
    coalesce(UnitCostO, UnitCostM) as UnitCostO  
FROM 
    ViewForCostAll 
WHERE
    iProductO = 7065 OR iProductM = 7065
```

You can use one column if another is null and then use DISTICNT to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

A join is what you do to combine rows. Once the join is done, you can compare values within the (internal resulting) row, and output selected results. This query only works for the 2 rows you asked about. If your data has more rows, let's see them and make a query that works for your actual data.

```
SELECT 
    isNull(V1.iProductM, V2.iProductM) as iProductM,
    isNull(V1.iProductO, V2.iProductO) as iProductO,
    isNull(V1.UnitCostM, V2.UnitCostM) as UnitCostM,  
    isNull(V1.UnitCostO, V2.UnitCostO) as UnitCostO  
FROM 
   ViewForCostAll V1
LEFT JOIN
   ViewforCostAll V2 on (V2.iProductM is null)
WHERE
    V1.iProductO = 7065
```

Comment: In my query ,I need to fetch cost and iProduct in the following conditions:If iProductM and iProductO has values ,I need iProductM value  only,if iProductM is null ,value has to come from iProductO,if iProductO is null ,value must be from iProductM,same case for unitcost also.Any suggestion?

Comment: The query above produces the result that you expected in your question "Required output". Please edit your question and add more data rows so I can understand your new requirement.

Comment: Its ok,I got the output,the above query also helped,along with that I added mine too